# For loop to change background color

Tags: java, for-loop, background-color

Hi I'm creating a Battleship program for my Java class. Right now, I'm trying to work on a class that fires shots. To fire, I'm trying to change the background color from blue(which means it is just an empty cell) to yellow (to show that I have fired in that cell but there is nothing there).

This is the code for the Fire class. I can include the other classes it inherits from if you think it's necessary. The main thing I'm having a problem with is trying to get my "for" loop to go through and really change the background from blue to yellow for the number of iterations I want it to. 100 is an arbitrary number for testing purposes.

```
public class Fire extends Ship{

    public Fire() throws InterruptedException{
        super.setShipV();
    }
    public void Shoot() throws InterruptedException {

        Random random= new Random();

        int a = random.nextInt(100);
        int b = random.nextInt(100);

        for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
           //for(int j = 0; j< 50; i++){
           grid[a][b].setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Hannah

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the iterator variables when accessing the grid.

Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j< 50; i++){
      grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.yellow);
}
```

or if you want to change 100 random fields put the `random.nextInt` inside the loops so `a` and `b` change in each iteration (The random values can hit the same values as previous iterations)

```
for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
   int a = random.nextInt(100);
   int b = random.nextInt(100);
   grid[a][b].setBackground(Color.yellow);
}
```

The only code that gets executed in each iteration is the code between `{` (after `for(..)`) and `}`. This means that in your code `a` and `b` are set once and then you are marking the same grid field yellow a hundred times. If you do it this way you give `a` and `b` a new value in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much. The second part worked. Why did it have to be done this way? What was wrong with the original way I was doing it? Definitely not necessary to answer, but I don't want to make the same mistake in the future.

Hannah

Comment: @HanH1113 Updated the answer with a little more explanation. Hope it makes it more clear. If not please say so, so I can improve it further. :)